# What to do when api returns html or json for different errors

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

Using python requests to talk to the github api.

```
response = requests.post('https://api.github.com/orgs/orgname/repos', auth, data)
```

If the request returns a 405 error I get HTML in the response.text

```
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

If the request returns a 422 error I get JSON  in the response.text

```
{"message":"Validation Failed","errors":        [{"resource":"Repository","code":"custom","field":"name","message":"name already exists on this account"}],"documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create"}
```

Can I force the API to only return JSON?

If not, can I find out what type the response content will be?

Comment: To find what kind of response the content will be in you could check the `http response code`!

Comment: Also as I read here: https://developer.github.com/v3/#schema all data is sent and received as `JSON`, so in your case it may be an authentication issue - or in other words you are trying to retrieve `not-allowed` content and that is maybe why the server doesn't send a response back, instead prints a not allowed message in `HTML` ...

Comment: You can go with `try: json.loads()` and then except with html.

Answer (score 1):

In response to:

> If not, can I find out what type the response content will be?

If you want to know why github returns html rather than JSON for the API call, I can not answer that; however, to the answer to the above asked question, you can look at the "content" header of the http response.

```
response = requests.post('https://api.github.com/orgs/orgname/repos', auth, data)
if "application/json" in response.headers['content-type']:
    print response.json()
```

In response to:

> Can I force the API to only return JSON?
>    you could try forcing the "Accept header within the request; however, this is down to GitHub server if it wants to serve json in the response

```
response = requests.post('https://api.github.com/orgs/omnifone/repos', auth=auth, data=data, headers={"Accept": "application/json"})
```